# What causes error in IE7?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using this JS code to reach a list of cities. It works in fireworks, chrome .e.t.c. But in ie7 it does not. the line `document.getElementById(oDiv).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` causes the error.

When I change "responseText" to "readyState", "statusText", "readyState" the scripts works.  Only "responseText" causes problem.

What is the problem here?

```
function showAjax(oDiv, countrycode, dowhat) {
    if (oDiv == "") {
        document.getElementById(oDiv).innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'ajax.php?dowhat=' + dowhat + '&countrycode=' + countrycode, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(oDiv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            //document.getElementById(oDiv).innerHTML=xmlhttp.readyState;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

`<a href='#' onclick="showAjax('citytd','$countrycode','listcities')">Click</a>`
`<div  id=citytd></div>`

Comment: Old IE versions does'nt neccessarily have the same names for methods as other browsers, especially in ajax functions. Just do a check to see which one is available in the browser.

Comment: @adeneo: `getElementById`, `innerHTML`, and `XHR#responseText` go back to IE 5.5 at least. :-) Doesn't mean they *function* properly, but they're there.

Comment: @ mustafa: *"...causes the error."* **What** error, exactly?

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder: Infact there is no true error. ie open ups saying there is an unknown error  pointing the line number only

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yup, I know, and onreadystatechange was introduced in IE7, so that should be there too. IE sucks!

Answer (score 0):

IE7 (and before, and IE8 in "compatibility" mode) has issues with `getElementById`, where it considers some things IDs that it shouldn't. I suspect you have a global variable, or another element with `name="citytd"`, and IE is pick that up instead (even though, again, it shouldn't). More: [*...by any other name, would smell as sweet*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html)

Comment: Crowder: I am sure there is no another citytd. I also tried with a different id.

Comment: @mustafa: Then you'll need to create a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem, I'm not immediately seeing an issue otherwise.